# Prevent Chart Data Labels from Being Obscured

Tags: c#, .net, charts, label, mschart

I am building an application using .net to automatically generate charts and save them into memory streams from data. I met the problem of data labels being obscured by other series. I enabled the following.

```
series.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true
series.SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes
series.SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false
series.SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Right
```

And data label can still be obscured by other data series, as the example shown below.

[image: Example]

So the question is, how can I make all data labels visible and clear?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If that matters, I selectively enable data label on the series when a DataPoint is added.

Edit 2:  I add data points one by one using `Points.AddXY(SomeDate.ToOADate(), SomeValue)`. I go through the data, and add one point to each series, and enable the data label under some conditions. The critical part is like the following.

```
var index = series1.Points.AddXY(date.ToOADate(), value)
series2.Points.AddXY(date.ToOADate(), value)
series3.Points.AddXY(date.ToOADate(), value)

if (some condition)
{
    series1.Points.[index].IsValueShownAsLabel = true
    series2.Points.[index].IsValueShownAsLabel = true
    series3.Points.[index].IsValueShownAsLabel = true
}
```

I set the SmartLabelStyle for each series, and then add the series to the chart, and then add data points to the series.

Comment: What ChartType are those series?

Comment: @TaW Line and Column.

Comment: OK. (I asked because FastLine doesn't support SmartLabels..) - I guess it has to do with the way you add the Points, but I really don't know. And of course I can't reproduce, which would be most helpful...

Comment: @TaW Thank you for clarifying. I updated the question to have more information.